# Calling an abstract method in super class's construtor in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Since the subclass is not constructed yet, is it unsafe to call an abstract method in a super class constructor?

However, if the method's behaviour does not depend on the constrction of subclass, e.g. just return a constant with regard to the subclass, is it still unsafe or will it work reliably?

Moreover, if it works, how to do it if I do not want to make the super class abstract?

**Update: for last question**

```
public class SuperClass {
      public SuperClass() {
          System.out.println(getValue());
      }   

      public String getValue() {
          return "superclass";
      }   

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           new SubClass();
      }

}


class SubClass extends SuperClass {
      public SubClass() {
           super(); // Comment out this or not  will not affect the result
      }   

      public String getValue() {
           return "subclass";
       }   
}
```

I wrote a test, and figure it out: the result is : `subclass` 
Thanks to @Tim Pote's example.

Comment: Your second question doesn't make sense; a non-abstract class cannot have an abstract method.

Comment: The first question doesn't make a whole lot of sense either.

Comment: @NullUserException Eh, it makes enough sense. It's roughly akin to calling a virtual method in a constructor (frowned upon) only *worse*, since it's guaranteed that the actual implementation is in a not-yet-constructed class.

Comment: @dlev Ok, I konw, I just want to mean to implement polymorphism .

Comment: Why not just pass the "constant with regard to the subclass" as an argument to the super class constructor instead of using an abstract method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally (though not necessarily) considered unsafe.  As you said, the superclass may not be fully constructed, and therefore won't be ready to handle all of the calls a subclass might make in its overridden method.

However, in the case that *all* subclasses simply return a constant that isn't dependent on any other method, then it should be fine.  The only downside is that you can't guarantee that a subclass will override that method in an appropriate manner.

In regards to your last question: this isn't an issue of an abstract vs. concrete superclass.  This is an issue with calling overridable methods in a constructor.  Abstract vs. concrete is beside the point.

---

**Edit in response to the OP's comment**

I'm not certain what you mean by "polymorphiscly".  Calling a virtual method always invokes the sub-most implementation.  The only time a superclasses implementation is invoked is via the `super` keyword.  For example:

```
public class SuperClass {
  public SuperClass() {
    System.out.println(getValue());
  }   

  public String getValue() {
    return "superclass";
  }   

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SubClass();
  }   

  public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public String getValue() {
      return "subclass";
    }   
  }   
}
```

prints `subclass`.

And this:

```
public class SuperClass {
  public SuperClass() {
    System.out.println(getValue());
  }   

  public String getValue() {
    return "superclass";
  }   

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SubClass();
  }   

  public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public String getValue() {
      return super.getValue() + " subclass";
    }   
  }   
}
```

prints `superclass subclass`

Comment: It's not an issue of calling overridable methods - only *overridden* methods that rely on as-of-yet-invalid state. (If a tree never falls ..) As dlev pointed out in a comment it's sort of hard to not have an "overridden" abstract method, though ..

Comment: @pst I took the OP's last question to mean essentially "what changes if I make the superclass concrete".  The answer is: nothing changes.  As long as subcasses are overriding methods used in the constructor of the superclass, you still have the same issue on your hands.

Comment: If the super class is abstract, not doubt Java will force programmer to implement it in subclass, and all I need to gurantee is to carefully make sure the implementation does not rely on the other part of the subclass(since it is not constructed yet). However, if due to some reason I do not want to make super abstract, then can I or how can I to achieve the goal that method in super's constrctor behave polymorphiscly  ?

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained there is an inherent risk in calling abstract methods in super class constructor.

The one exception I have found is when the subclass provides some "constant" information, e.g `getId()`, `getHandledMessages()` and suchlike.